# Spring deployed into JBOSS 7 not loading hibernate entities

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jboss7.x, entitymanager

I have a Spring MVC application that was created using roo configured with jpa using hibernate. It creates the database and works fine deployed into the STS provided tomcat server. However when deployed into JBOSS 7.1.1 AS it seems not to find the entities.  I have tried following [JBoss Spring Migration Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Spring+applications+development+and+migration+guide).  I want to allow spring to be the entity manager while still deploying to JBOSS with minimal configuration changes from the default spring tomcat configuration. I have been able to get this to work when I allow JBOSS to be the entity manager but would like to do less configuration changes than this method requires. The code and log is what I have found from various websites describing how they overcame this issue but it doesn't seem to work for my deployment.

META-INF/spring/applicationContext-jpa.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.lmco.lmis.setup.EncryptedBasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <!-- <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" 
        id="dataSource"> -->
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
    <property name="testOnReturn" value="true" />
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000" />
    <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3" />
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000" />
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/jpa-persistence.xml" />
</bean>
```

META-INF/jpa-persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="jpaHibernatePersistenceUnit"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="jboss.as.jpa.managed" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
        <!-- value="create" to build a new database on each run; value="update" 
            to modify an existing database; value="create-drop" means the same as "create" 
            but also drops tables when Hibernate closes; value="validate" makes no changes 
            to the database -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />
        <!-- Uncomment the following two properties for JBoss only -->
        <property name="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners"
            value="false" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.hibernate" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

JBOSS server.log

```
17:49:54,841 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-2) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
17:49:54,898 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (MSC service thread 1-2) Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Feb 08 17:49:54 EST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
17:49:55,027 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] (MSC service thread 1-2) Loading XML bean definitions from "/C:/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/lmis.war/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-jpa.xml"
17:49:56,011 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] (MSC service thread 1-2) Loading XML bean definitions from "/C:/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/lmis.war/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-security.xml"
17:49:56,174 INFO  [org.springframework.security.core.SpringSecurityCoreVersion] (MSC service thread 1-2) You are running with Spring Security Core 3.1.0.RELEASE
17:49:56,177 INFO  [org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler] (MSC service thread 1-2) Spring Security 'config' module version is 3.1.0.RELEASE
17:49:56,219 INFO  [org.springframework.security.config.http.FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSourceParser] (MSC service thread 1-2) Creating access control expression attribute 'hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')' for /choices/**
17:49:56,222 INFO  [org.springframework.security.config.http.FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSourceParser] (MSC service thread 1-2) Creating access control expression attribute 'isAuthenticated()' for /member/**
17:49:56,224 INFO  [org.springframework.security.config.http.FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSourceParser] (MSC service thread 1-2) Creating access control expression attribute 'permitAll' for /resources/**
17:49:56,226 INFO  [org.springframework.security.config.http.FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSourceParser] (MSC service thread 1-2) Creating access control expression attribute 'permitAll' for /**
17:49:56,245 INFO  [org.springframework.security.config.http.HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser] (MSC service thread 1-2) Checking sorted filter chain: [Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 300, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 400, <org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0>, order = 800, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1200, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1300, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1400, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1700, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1800, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1900, <org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0>, order = 2000]
17:49:56,275 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] (MSC service thread 1-2) Loading XML bean definitions from "/C:/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/lmis.war/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml"
17:49:56,308 INFO  [org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner] (MSC service thread 1-2) JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
17:49:56,311 INFO  [org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner] (MSC service thread 1-2) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
17:49:57,479 INFO  [org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer] (MSC service thread 1-2) Loading properties file from "/C:/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/lmis.war/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/database.properties"
17:49:57,496 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-2) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
17:49:57,603 INFO  [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] (MSC service thread 1-2) Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'jpaHibernatePersistenceUnit'
17:49:57,775 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (MSC service thread 1-2) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
17:49:57,780 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.1.8.Final}
17:49:57,784 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
17:49:57,786 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
17:49:57,804 INFO  [org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: jpaHibernatePersistenceUnit
    ...]
17:49:57,913 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
17:49:58,383 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
17:49:58,393 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
17:49:58,403 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory
17:49:58,407 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
17:49:58,463 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-2) Hibernate Validator 4.2.0.Final
17:49:58,507 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
17:49:58,511 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000230: Schema export complete
17:49:58,543 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] (MSC service thread 1-2) Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@14f0e813: defining beans [dataSource,transactionManager,entityManagerFactory,org.springframework.security.filterChains,org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy,org.springframework.security.web.PortMapperImpl#0,org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0,org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy#0,org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler#0,org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0,org.springframework.security.userDetailsServiceFactory,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0,org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher#0,org.springframework.security.authenticationManager,org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer#0,org.springframework.context.config.internalBeanConfigurerAspect,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAspect,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
17:49:58,825 INFO  [org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain] (MSC service thread 1-2) Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@2f7d54e1, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@4d4f9822, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@248d07d5, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@26fd43b2, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@3d676f1d, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@51aff869, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@77dddf64, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@7755bb7, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@29d84f34, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@3837f462]
17:49:58,858 INFO  [org.springframework.security.config.http.DefaultFilterChainValidator] (MSC service thread 1-2) Checking whether login URL '/login' is accessible with your configuration
17:49:58,999 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-2) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4156 ms
17:49:59,334 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/lmis]] (MSC service thread 1-2) Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'lmis'
17:49:59,337 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (MSC service thread 1-2) FrameworkServlet 'lmis': initialization started
17:49:59,342 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (MSC service thread 1-2) Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'lmis-servlet': startup date [Fri Feb 08 17:49:59 EST 2013]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
17:49:59,347 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] (MSC service thread 1-2) Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml]
17:49:59,930 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-2) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
17:49:59,942 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] (MSC service thread 1-2) Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@62f314a8: defining beans [assignedCertificationController,certificationController,certificationSourceController,courseController,courseSeriesController,courseSeriesTemplateController,courseTemplateController,employeeController,jobCertificationGroupController,manualCertificationGroupController,qualificationController,qualificationLogController,titleCertificationGroupController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,mvcContentNegotiationManager,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#1,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#1,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#2,org.springframework.web.servlet.config.viewControllerHandlerMapping,messageSource,localeResolver,themeSource,themeResolver,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver#0,multipartResolver,tilesViewResolver,tilesConfigurer,applicationConversionService,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@14f0e813
17:50:00,147 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-2) Mapped "{[/assignedcertifications],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[text/html],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.lmco.lmis.web.AssignedCertificationController.list(java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Integer,org.springframework.ui.Model)
```

Comment: I'm not sure it matters, but try ` <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/jpa-persistence.xml" />`. The documentation has an `*` after the CP.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is not necessity in *jboss-deployment-structure.xml* and *jpaVendorAdapter* property.
But you should add the list of entity classes in the persistence unit.
The description and example are in [JBoss documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/reference/build/reference/en/html/entityconfig.html)

At-leaset, that works for me

Answer (score 0):

Standalone Hibernate up to version 4.2 is unable to scan Entities when running in JBoss.

The class responsible for scanning `org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.JarVisitorFactory` doesn't handle the JBoss VFS protocol.

A possible workaround is to use Spring (>3.1.x) to do the scanning. Class `org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` has a property `packagesToScan` which can be set to something like `com.company.**.*`.

Note: Hibernate 4.3 redesigns the scanning in new package `org.hibernate.jpa.boot.scan`, I haven't tried this version.